# Polars native API instead of the slow "map_elements"

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I have a dataframe with fields `age`, `diagnosis`, etc that I'm reading from a csv file. I need to add a column `code` (a disease code) that depends on `diagnosis` and/or `age`. I am currently using the `map_elements` method:

```py
disease_codes = {
"malaria": {"under_5": "a", "over_5": "b"},
"PUD": "c",
"Asthma": "d",
}
# The callable to return the appropriate code
def return_code(row):
    diagnosis = row["diagnosis"]
    age = row["age"]
    dx_return = disease_codes.get(diagnosis, "Undefined")
    if type(dx_return) == dict:
        if age >= 5:
            return dx_return.get("over_5")
        return dx_return.get("under_5")
    return dx_return
df.with_columns(pl.struct(["diagnosis", "age"]).map_elements(return_code).alias("code"))
```

This is working as expected. But because this method uses a `for` loop, there is a warning in the [docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_elements.html):

> This method is much slower than native expressions API. Only use it if you cannot implement your logic otherwise.

I have been trying to find a way to achieve it with the native API and I thought `map_batches` came close:

```py
def return_code(diagnosis, age):
    dx_return = disease_codes.get(diagnosis, "Undefined")
    if type(dx_return) == dict:
        if age >= 5:
            return dx_return.get("over_5")
        return dx_return.get("under_5")
    return dx_return

df.with_columns(
    (pl.struct(["diagnosis", "age"]).map_batches(
        lambda x: return_code(x.struct.field("diagnosis"), x.struct.field("age"))
    )).alias("code")
)
```

Apparently, I can't do that as I get an error:

```py
TypeError: cannot use `__getitem__` on Series of dtype Struct([Field('diagnosis', Utf8), Field('age', Int64)]) with argument 'diagnosis' of type 'str'
```

Looking at the documentation, this is by far the only method I thought would do the trick. Am I stuck with the slower approach? Is there something I am not doing right? What would you suggest?

The expected output, which I am getting with the working approach, should be:
[image]

Comment: Can you transform `disease_codes`? e.g. turn `"PUD": "c"` into `"PUD": {"under_5": "c", "over_5": "c"}` - if you make `disease_codes` a dataframe of `diagnosis, under_5, over_5` you could `.join()` then use when/then as @Hericks has shown for the `age`.

Comment: I certainly can, and will, do this. This is more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1.** You could use a [*when-then-otherwise* expression](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html) as follows:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "age": [2, 37, 53, 1, 52],
    "diagnosis": ["Malaria", "PUD", "Malaria", "PUD", "Other"],
})

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("diagnosis") == "Malaria").then(
            pl.when(pl.col("age") < 5).then(pl.lit("a")).otherwise(pl.lit("b"))
        ).otherwise(
            pl.when(pl.col("diagnosis") == "PUD").then(pl.lit("c")).otherwise(pl.lit("d"))
        ).alias("disease_code"),
    )
)
```

[image]

If there are many conditions depending only on a single column (e.g. `diagnosis`) and few depending on another column (e.g. `age`), it might be reasonable to first start with [`pl.map_dict`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_dict.html). Subsequently, you could handle the `age`-dependant special cases with the when-then-otherwise expressions as outlined above.

---

**Method 2.** Alternatively, you could create (using any method) a table of disease codes, add the necessary columns to `df`, and merge the tables.

This could look look as follows:

```
disease_codes = pl.DataFrame({
    "diagnosis": ["Malaria"] * 2 + ["PUD"] * 2 + ["Other"] * 2,
    "le_5": [True, False] * 3,
    "code": ["a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d"]
})

(
    df
    .with_columns(le_5=pl.col("age") < 5)
    .join(disease_codes, on=["diagnosis", "le_5"], how="left")
    .drop("le_5")
)
```

The output will be identical the one shown above.

Comment: This a great pointer! I hesitated to use `map_dict` because my the disease_codes dictionary didn't have uniform values. I completely overlooked the fact that I don't have as many two-column dependant values as I do single-column ones.

Comment: While I'm sure I can make it work with your suggestion, I think an elegant approach will be transforming the `disease_codes` dictionary into a dataframe as suggested by @jqurious. And sort of combine the conditional expression.

Comment: @McPherson Great. For completeness, I've added an example of this method to the answer.